# Books about chaos theory

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-economics

For someone who already knows micro and macro economics, are there any good books to understand chaos theory in economics and mathematical economics in general?

Comment: You mean "bifurcations and cycles" by chaos ?

Answer (score 2):

Some older references, from the first wave of fascination with the subject:

1) [Baumol, W. J., & Benhabib, J. (1989). Chaos: significance, mechanism, and economic applications. The journal of economic perspectives, 77-105.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1942966)

A general introductory overview.

2) [Lorenz, H. W. (1993). Nonlinear dynamical economics and chaotic motion (Vol. 334). Berlin: Springer.](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-22233-1)

Theoretical treatment

3) [Brock, W. A., Hsieh, D. A., & LeBaron, B. (1991). Nonlinear dynamics, chaos, and instability.](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/nonlinear-dynamics-chaos-and-instability)

Applied econometrics for the detection of chaotic behavior in economic time-series, from two of the most known researchers in the field (W. Brock and B. LeBaron)/